# Error when saving VisualForce email template "Error: Invalid Field"

Tags: visualforce, email, email-template, repeat

I am following [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/VisualForceEmailTemplates_sample) SF VF email example.

They have the  `relatedToType="Account"` and their `<apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.Cases}">` references Cases which should loop through the Cases related to Account - Being a one to many relationship.  I can make this work fine.

When I change the `relatedToType="Contact"` and my `<apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.MyCustomObject__r}">` which is also a one to many relationship I get the following error on trying to save the template:

> Error: Invalid field MyCustomObject__r for SObject Contact

I have also tried __c but with the same error.

Any ideas?

> UPDATE:
>
> The accepted answer below (and comments) worked for me.  I was
>   focusing on the related 'object' not the 'field' that actually related
>   them both together.

Comment: Get the child relationship name and append __r there .

Comment: The child relationship name is usually plural (unless you've manually changed it), and you have to use __r. So use `{!relatedTo.MyCustomObjects__r}`. You can see the child relationship name, by going to the lookup field, it's at the bottom left.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The child relationship name has to be observed and __r needs to be appended .

[image]

In your set up menu navigate to Object > field > and observe child relationship name